# A birational map from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to an irreducible plane projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Let $C$ be an irreducible plane projective curve described by the equation
$$zf(x, y) + g(x, y) = 0,$$
where $f$ and $g$ are a homogenous forms of degree $d - 1$ and $d$, respectively. What would be the birational map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to C$?

Comment: Notice that for each x and y there is a unique Z which makes the equation hold...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Yes, but how do I come up with an explicit example of a birational curve?

Comment: If I give you a point (x:y) in the projective line, can you construct a point in the curve C?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez This is my question.

Comment: Well, my first comment was the observation that if x and y are given, there is exactly one z which makes the equation hold. Can you maybe, possibly, use that observation to construct from a point (x:y) in the projective line a point in the curve C?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Algebra is not my strong suit. I cannot tell whether the answer is trivial or not.

Comment: Trivial are the things you see —stop caring about whether things are trivial, as it helps no one.

Comment: If I give you x and y, what is the unique Z such that the equation holds?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Well, $z = -g(x, y)/f(x, y)$.

Comment: If I give you (x:y) in the projective line, can you construct a point in the curve whose first two coordinates are x and y?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez If $z = -g(x, y)/f(x, y)$, the point would be $[x : y : -g(x, y)/f(x, y)]$.

Comment: Can you think of a function going from the projective line to the curve C?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Can we just define it by $F([x : y]) : [x : y] \mapsto [x : y : -g/f]$?

Comment: Notice  that irreducibility of $C$ translates into $f$ and $g$ being relatively prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, one can try the function $$F:(x:y)\in P^1\longmapsto \bigl(x:y:-\tfrac{g(x,y)}{f(x,y)}\bigr)\in P^2.$$ This has image contained in the curve $C$. It is important that this is well-defined: the point $(x:y)$ is equal to $(\lambda x:\lambda y)$, and the points $(x:y:-\tfrac{g(x,y)}{f(x,y)}\bigr)$ and $(\lambda x:\lambda y:-\tfrac{g(\lambda x,\lambda y)}{f(\lambda x,\lambda y)}\bigr)$ are also equal, precisely because $f$ and $g$ are homogeneous of the degrees they have.

Notice that the map is defined only at the points $(x:y)$ of $P^1$ where $f(x,y)\neq0$; this is not a big problem: there are finitely many such points. The domain of our function is the open set which is complementary to the zero set of $f$.

On the other hand, we have a function $$G:(x:y:z)\in C\longmapsto (x:y)\in P^1.$$ You should find exactly where this is defined and check that it is actually well-defined. Finally, you should check that $F$ and $G$ are inverse in the appropriate sense.

Comment: The rational map $F$ is (=can be extended to) a regular morphism defined at all points of $\mathbb P^1$, even those with $f(x,y)=0$  where the formula apparently fails. Indeed, a rational map from a smooth curve to a projective variety is actually a regular morphism (Hartshorne Chap. I, Prop. 6.8, page 43).